# Extjs Charts: remove as series using chart.series.getAt(0) how?

Tags: extjs, charts, series

Hello how can I remove a series from a chart, I know that I can get the series object using getAt(0) or getAt(1) depending on how many serieses I got in my chart.
my question is how can I remove a series from the chart.
main reason is that I give the end user the ability to change the series type: bar, line... so I wan to display the new change at run time by removing the series and adding a new one.

I tried Chart.series.removeAt(0); It removes the legend but the bar or the line still shown !!

I use extjs 4.1.1

thank you,

Comment: try hiding the series before removing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same thing and give end users the ability to change the chart type at run time to give different visualizations of data. I found that there is more involved in the chart type (bar, line, pie) then just the series. In other words to achieve this, I wasn't able to just substitute a different series type for the data and add it to the chart.

I ended up creating a different config for each different type of chart using the same datastore. The chart was contained by an `Ext.panel.Panel` which I added this function to:

```
// toggle format between pie chart and bar chart
this.toggleFormat = function() {
    var chart = me.down('chart');

    this.remove(chart);
    if (chart.chartType == 'pie') {
        this.add(Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', bar));
    } else {
        this.add(Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', pie));
    }
};
```

The `bar` variable holds a bar chart config and `pie` holds a pie chart config but both had the same datastore attached to their `store:` configs.

When the user pressed the format button I called this function to remove the chart from the panel and create one with the different format. It achieved the desired effect.